# Induction proof to find formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I ran into some problem when I am doing some review.
I need to find the formula for the following by exploring the cases n = 1,2,3,4 and prove by induction

I have this sequence

$$a_n = 1/(1*2) + 1/(2*3) + 1/(3*4) + ...... + 1/n(n+1)$$

I know how to do it when they give you the formula, but how will you find the formula for this example?

help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, we have that $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The general trick is the partial fraction decomposition. See the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Did you explore the cases $n=1,2,3,4$ as the problem asked?

If you did, you would had discovered the following

When $n=1$ then $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$.

When $n=2$ then $a_2=\frac{2}{3}$.

When $n=3$ then $a_3=\frac{3}{4}$.

When $n=4$ then $a_4=\frac{4}{5}$.

Can you identify the pattern from here? Staring at those numbers, what do you think $a_n$ is going to be? Once you guessed, you have the formula you need to prove.

Comment: ahhh. I got it so it will be n/(n+1)