# Hint to find a Closed Form of $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, closed-form

This problem is the Exercise from [Discrete Mathematics book, p.24](https://staff.informatics.buu.ac.th/~seree/888204/discretemath.pdf).
The problem says

> Find the a closed form of $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$

I tried these ways with no luck

## Re-index and plus themself

- Replace k with k + 1

  From
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$
  Replace k with k + 1
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k + 1 \leq n}\frac{1}{(k + 1)(k + 2)}$$
  Add -1 all through the inequation
  $$S_n = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n - 1}\frac{1}{(k + 1)(k + 2)}$$
  The range is not matched with original. So, I think I cannot go further.
- Replace k with k - 2

  From
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$
  Replace k with k - 2
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k - 2 \leq n}\frac{1}{(k - 2)(k - 1)}$$
  Add +2 all through the inequation
  $$S_n = \sum_{3 \leq k \leq n + 2}\frac{1}{(k - 2)(k - 1)}$$
  The range is not matched with original. So, I think I cannot go further.
- Replace k with n - k + 1

  From
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$
  Replace k with n - k + 1
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq n - k + 1 \leq n}\frac{1}{(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2)}$$
  Tune the inequation
  $$S_n = \sum_{0 \leq n - k \leq n - 1}\frac{1}{(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2)}$$
  $$S_n = \sum_{-n \leq -k \leq -1}\frac{1}{(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2)}$$
  $$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2)}$$
  Try adding them together
  $$2S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}(\frac{1}{k(k + 1)} + \frac{1}{(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2)})$$
  $$2S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2) + k(k + 1)} {k(k + 1)(n - k + 1)(n - k + 2)}$$
  I decide not to go further. Is this the dead end?

## Plus with extra boundary

From 
$$S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$
Add $$\frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)}$$ to both side
$$S_n + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)}$$
$$S_n + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n + 1}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$
Adjust the inequation
$$S_n + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq k - 1 \leq n}\frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$$
Replace k with k + 1
$$S_n + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{(k + 1)(k + 2)}$$
From this point, I have no idea to go next.

Can anyone give me a clue? Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655232/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Induction proof to find formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655232/induction-proof-to-find-formula)

Answer (score 1):

In general, try calculating this kind of thing for several small $n$. You might see a pattern. $$\{S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4,\ldots\}=\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\ldots\right\}$$ Does a pattern jump out? If you can propose a formula for $S_n$, you could try induction to prove that formula is correct.